# GCE + Hadoop: Not being able to create disk on more than 9 machines

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to follow the example in:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-google-compute-engine-cluster-for-hadoop

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=se9vV8eIZME

and when I get to the command to start the cluster:

`./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py start cosightio cosightio-hadoop-sample 97`

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 230, in <module>
    main()
  File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 226, in main
    ComputeClusterForHadoop().ParseArgumentsAndExecute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 222, in ParseArgumentsAndExecute
    params.handler(params)
  File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 41, in Start
    gce_cluster.GceCluster(flags).StartCluster()
  File "/Users/dsinha/Dropbox/code/solutions-google-compute-engine-cluster-for-hadoop/gce_cluster.py", line 380, in StartCluster
    self._StartInstance(self._WorkerName(i), role='worker')
  File "/Users/dsinha/Dropbox/code/solutions-google-compute-engine-cluster-for-hadoop/gce_cluster.py", line 210, in _StartInstance
    self._WaitForDiskReady(data_disk_name)
  File "/Users/dsinha/Dropbox/code/solutions-google-compute-engine-cluster-for-hadoop/gce_cluster.py", line 179, in _WaitForDiskReady
    'Persistent disk %s creation timed out.' % disk_name)
gce_cluster.ClusterSetUpError: Persistent disk hw-009-data creation timed out.
```

When I tried this on asia-east1-c, it used to get stuck creating the 8th instance, when I changed it back to us-central1-a, it gets stuck at 9.

How can I debug this further? Thanks!

Edit:
Just realized my quotas are still at default, so was wondering if they are causing an issue? I think the example has 100 machines each having 500 GB disk, so perhaps I need to request for a quota increase to:

```
CPUs    0   24
Total persistent disk reserved (GB) 200 5,120
```

to 100 and 100,000 respectively? Trying this out now...

Comment: Yes, if you want to spin up a 100-machine Hadoop cluster, you will need to submit a request for quota increase. Don't forget to include all the resources: CPUs, RAM and disk (persistent and/or SSD, depending on what you plan to use) in your request.

Comment: To request a quota increase for Compute Engine please use the following form: https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1vb2MkAr9JcHrp6myQ3oTxCyBv2c7Iyc5wqIKqE3K4IE/viewform

Answer (score 0):

By default, on-line billing projects (payment as-you-go for used resources, usually by credit card) have [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas).

The scenario you describe is most certainly hitting the core quota limit, which is by default 24 (as of this writing). In order to deploy such a large cluster, a quota increase request has to be turned in, keeping in mind large increase requests need to be vetted prior to actioning, providing a "bona fide" justification for the increase via the [quota increase request form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1vb2MkAr9JcHrp6myQ3oTxCyBv2c7Iyc5wqIKqE3K4IE/viewform) .